# venting kitchen sink in a cabin

Tags: plumbing

e have a small cabin on a lake that as mainly used for weekends. Now that we have retired we have been living here full time. Our kitchen sink goes from under the sink, out the wall and into a gray water catchment. There is no vent and it empties very slowly. I have a 2 sided sink and it will come up on both sides when it drains. My husband say that since it goes out from the sink and straight out the wall and straight down that it doesn't need a vent. I say that when it goes out the wall their sound be a vent on that pipe so the water runs faster and doesn't back up into the other side o the sink too.Couldn't we put a connector on the pipe outside of the wall that has 2 openings? One or the pipe going down and one for a vent line?

Answer (score 1):

A better option might be adding an Air Admittance Valve under the sink.  It will just take a little bit of work to change the pipe between the p-trap and wall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install what's called a "*street wye*" or a "*sanitary tee*". This will allow the water to drain down into the cistern, while also providing you a place to install a vent.

[image: Street wye installation]

---

[image: Sanitary tee installation]

#### NOTES:

- The size and material of the wye/tee will depend on the size and material of the drain pipe.
- The end of the vent pipe must extend up to be at least above the flood level of the sink (must be higher than the rim of the sink). So you'll likely have to install a bit of pipe going up from the wye/tee.
- An air admittance valve (AAV) *may* provide a simpler solution (may or may not be code compliant).

[image]